# Alimentar div que foram criadas dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

Em Jquery estou criando divs dinamicamente assim:

```
var totalLoop = 2;
var escreveReceitas = '';
for (i = 1; i <= totalLoop; i++) {
    escreveReceitas += '<div class="produtos_titulo" id="titulo'+i+'"></div>';
}
$('.receitas').html(escreveReceitas);
```

O resultado:

```
<div class="produtos_titulo" id="titulo1"></div>
<div class="produtos_titulo" id="titulo2"></div>
```

Agora tenho que alimentar os IDs titulo1 e titulo2, como fazer isso uma vez que eles foram criados dinamicamente? Tentei assim:

```
for (i = 1; i <= totalLoop; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'receitas/titulo'+i+'.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        success : function (resposta) {
            $('#titulo'+i).html(resposta);
        }
    });
}
```

Mas nada acontece, fica vazio... Só que os arquivos titulo1.txt e titulo2.txt estão com conteúdo...

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim, você já insere sua div e o conteúdo ao mesmo tempo.

```
for (i = 1; i <= totalLoop; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'receitas/titulo'+i+'.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        success : function (resposta) {
            $(".receitas").append('<div class="produtos_titulo" id="titulo'+i+'">'+resposta+'</div>');
        }
    });
}
```